# MongoDB Aggregation Data Returned

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am using MongoDB Aggregation to query two different schema collections.

```
Artist.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { artistID }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "userID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "UsersWithMatchedArtist"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            UsersWithMatchedArtist: 1
        }
    }
}
])
```

This returns a the following data structure.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "59f8f40686f2fa623d815256",
    "UsersWithMatchedArtist": [{Users Schema}]
  },
  {
    "_id": "59f8f40686f2f12345678901",
    "UsersWithMatchedArtist": [{Users Schema}}]
  }
]
```

I wish to have the data returned in the following structure

```
[
  {Users Schema},
  {Users Schema}
]
```

Any Suggestions on how to do this? Suggestions would be much appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: Use `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot`. Or `$project` every field in `Users Schema` after the `$unwind` if you don't have `$replaceRoot`. Or are you actually asking "return all users that have **an artist entry**"? The `$match` stage implies the former rather than the latter, but your question could be clearer.

Comment: Thanks mate, $replaceRoot looks awesome!

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired results, you can add $unwind and $group to the existing pipeline.

```
[
    {
        "$match": { artistID }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "userID",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "UsersWithMatchedArtist"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "UsersWithMatchedArtist": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$UsersWithMatchedArtist"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,    // or add your own grouping
            "UsersWithMatchedArtist": {"$push": "$UsersWithMatchedArtist"}
        }
    }
}]
```

Your output will be of the form:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "users" : [ 
        {Users Schema}, 
        {Users Schema}
    ]
}
```